# Thymeleaf equivalent of EL <c:import>

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, el

Is there in thymeleaf an equivalence to EL well known `<c:import></c:import>`?
I want to include one of my controllers *(or an external)* in an view. Thanks. I've found `th:insert` and `th:replace` but only the second one is recognized in my **spring-boot** template and it can only include an HTML file, so I'm waiting for your answers. Thank you.

Comment: You would likely need to implement http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/ITemplateResolver.html to do so